# Why is good to check for "false" first in an if statement?

Tags: php, performance, if-statement, conditional-statements

For example the following code tests for false first then truth. Is there any performance benefits or time saving doing this?

```
if (!touch('some_file.txt', $time)) {
    echo 'Whoops, something went wrong...';
} else {
    echo 'Touched file with success';
}
```

instead of

```
if (touch('some_file.txt', $time)) {
    echo 'Touched file with success';
} else {
    echo 'Whoops, something went wrong...';
}
```

Comment: @Andreas `touch` is php core function.

Comment: @arkascha No, OP asks why the condition is checked as `false`. You can write it as `if (touch())` also.

Comment: The question is, does `touch()` have to be executed in any case? Answer is yes, so there is no performance benefit testing false (or true) first. The compiler might save a nanosecond compiling without a `!`... but besides...

Comment: In my honest oppinion, checking if a file exist is more relevant if you target a specific case. If the case has multiple outcomes, with multiple outcomes, its better to check first if it all exists. Else technically does the rest, so if your code is based on the fact if something exists, you check first if it does exist, rather than if it doesnt exist. I dont think it is has any benefits performance wise.

Comment: IMHO - I always try and check for true first if it makes sense to (i.e. if it actually does something) as it can be easier for people to read - so easy to miss a `!` when scanning code.

Comment: Could be a leftover of defensive programming, here it could be an early guard with a null or false return or thrown exception.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, checking for "false" is not a question performance, it's a question of Cyclomatic complexity. Let me make it clear:
Imagine that you have to get 4 or 5 conditions true before you'd be able to make an action:

```
if (condition1 === true) {
    ...code

    if (condition2 === true) {
        ...code

        if (condition3 === true) {
            ...code

            if (condition4 === true) {
                ...code

                if (condition5 === true) {
                    ...code
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would be get really complicated to understand right ?
Now let's apply the "leave early" rule, by checking for "false".
The code below does exactly the same thing that does the code above:

```
if (condition1 === false) {
    return;
}

...code of condition 1 when is true
if (condition2 === false) {
    return;
}


...code of condition 2 when is true
if (condition3 === false) {
    return;
}


...code of condition 3 when is true
if (condition4 === false) {
    return;
}

...code of condition 4 when is true
if (condition5 === false) {
    return;
}

return value;
```

See how code is much cleaner and EASIER to read ? This is simply because you kept nested levels to the minimum instead of accumulating them.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on truth first but in main cases you would interact your code if false (for example file doesn't exists so you can put `return false` in if block.

And if you use `if (touch())` you have to write many code in {} block

Compare:

```
if (touch(file)) {
    //do something...
    // do domething else...
    if (file contensts) {
        //do something....
        //and so on...
        if() {
           // you can continue yourself...
        }
    }
    // continue...
}
```

and

```
if (!touch(file)) {
    throw new Error('some error');
    // or return false
}

//do something...
// do domething else...

if (!contents(file)) {
    return false;
}

// continue...
```

So for stick on one style everyone check on `false` first

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual performance benefit with having false in the first condition. However, personally I do this as practice to have a cleaner code. Usually if false should terminate the function.

```
if (!$true)
   return false;

long code...
```

Instead of having a very long braces that's quite hard to track sometimes.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean... Thanks @ACD.